# Symmetric transfer does not prevent stack-overflow for C++20 coroutines

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, c++20, clang++, c++-coroutine

According to the blog post [C++ Coroutines: Understanding Symmetric Transfer](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2020/05/11/understanding_symmetric_transfer) *symmetric transfer* allows you to suspend one coroutine and resume another without consuming any additional stack space. This prevents stack-overflows, which can occur when coroutines contain loops and `co_await` tasks that can potentially complete synchronously within the body of that loop.

Even though the following code example uses *symmetric transfer*, it crashes due to a stack-overflow. Please note that the code below is a minimal example to reproduce the stack-overflow: e.g., if I include the definition of the destructor of type `Type` in the header file, then I don't get a stack-overflow.

```
// type.h
#pragma once

struct Type {
  ~Type();
};
```

```
// type.cc
#include "type.h"

Type::~Type() {}
```

```
// main.cc
#include <cstdint>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

#include "type.h"

#if __has_include(<coroutine>)  // when using g++
#include <coroutine>
namespace coro {
using std::coroutine_handle;
using std::noop_coroutine;
using std::suspend_always;
}  // namespace coro
#elif __has_include(<experimental/coroutine>)  // when using clang++
#include <experimental/coroutine>
namespace coro {
using std::experimental::coroutine_handle;
using std::experimental::noop_coroutine;
using std::experimental::suspend_always;
}  // namespace coro
#endif

template <typename T = void>
class Task {
 public:
  struct PromiseBase {
    friend struct final_awaitable;

    struct final_awaitable {
      bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }

      template <typename PROMISE>
      coro::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(
          coro::coroutine_handle<PROMISE> coro) noexcept {
        if (coro.promise().m_continuation) {
          return coro.promise().m_continuation;
        } else {
          // The top-level task started from within main() does not have a
          // continuation. This will give control back to the main function.
          return coro::noop_coroutine();
        }
      }

      void await_resume() noexcept {}
    };

    coro::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

    auto final_suspend() noexcept { return final_awaitable{}; }

    void unhandled_exception() noexcept { std::terminate(); }

    void set_continuation(coro::coroutine_handle<> continuation) noexcept {
      m_continuation = continuation;
    }

   private:
    coro::coroutine_handle<> m_continuation;
  };

  struct PromiseVoid : public PromiseBase {
    auto get_return_object() { return coroutine_handle_t::from_promise(*this); }

    void return_void() noexcept {}

    void result() {}
  };

  struct PromiseT : public PromiseBase {
    auto get_return_object() { return coroutine_handle_t::from_promise(*this); }

    void return_value(T&& v) { value = std::move(v); }

    T&& result() && { return std::move(value); }

    T value;
  };

  using promise_type =
      std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, void>, PromiseVoid, PromiseT>;

  using coroutine_handle_t = coro::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

  Task(coroutine_handle_t coroutine) : m_coroutine(coroutine) {}

  ~Task() {
    if (m_coroutine) {
      m_coroutine.destroy();
    }
  }

  void start() noexcept { m_coroutine.resume(); }

  auto operator co_await() const noexcept { return awaitable{m_coroutine}; }

 private:
  struct awaitable {
    coroutine_handle_t m_coroutine;

    awaitable(coroutine_handle_t coroutine) noexcept : m_coroutine(coroutine) {}

    bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }

    coro::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(
        coro::coroutine_handle<> awaitingCoroutine) noexcept {
      m_coroutine.promise().set_continuation(awaitingCoroutine);
      return m_coroutine;
    }

    auto await_resume() { return std::move(m_coroutine.promise()).result(); }
  };
  coroutine_handle_t m_coroutine;
};

Task<Type> coro2() { co_return Type{}; }

Task<> coro1() { auto s = co_await coro2(); }

Task<> test() {
  for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i != 50000000; ++i) {
    co_await coro1();
  }
}

int main() {
  auto task = test();
  task.start();
}
```

I compile the code using `clang++ version 12.0.1` and `g++ version 11.1.0`:

```
clang++-12 main.cc type.cc -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -fsanitize=address
```

```
g++-11 main.cc type.cc -std=c++20 -O3 -fsanitize=address
```

Here is the truncated output for `clang++`:

```
$ ./a.out 

AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==20846==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffc76b1aff8 (pc 0x0000004cb7ab bp 0x7ffc76b1b050 sp 0x7ffc76b1afa0 T0)
    #0 0x4cb7ab in coro1() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cb7ab)
    #1 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #2 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #3 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #4 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #5 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #6 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #7 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #8 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #9 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #10 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #11 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #12 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #13 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #14 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #15 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #16 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #17 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #18 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #19 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #20 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #21 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #22 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #23 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #24 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
    #25 0x4cbe4a in test() (.resume) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x4cbe4a)
...
```

Here is the truncated output for `g++`:

```
$ ./a.out

AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==21434==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7fff2904dff8 (pc 0x7fd5f7825180 bp 0x7fff2904e880 sp 0x7fff2904dff0 T0)
    #0 0x7fd5f7825180 in __sanitizer::BufferedStackTrace::UnwindImpl(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*, bool, unsigned int) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_stack.cpp:57
    #1 0x7fd5f781b0eb in __sanitizer::BufferedStackTrace::Unwind(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*, bool, unsigned int) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_stacktrace.h:122
    #2 0x7fd5f781b0eb in operator delete(void*) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:160
    #3 0x5643118400b7 in _Z5coro2v.destroy(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x20b7)
    #4 0x564311840e36 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2e36)
    #5 0x56431183fe20 in _Z5coro2v.actor(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x1e20)
    #6 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #7 0x564311841741 in _Z4testv.actor(test()::_Z4testv.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x3741)
    #8 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #9 0x56431183fe20 in _Z5coro2v.actor(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x1e20)
    #10 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #11 0x564311841741 in _Z4testv.actor(test()::_Z4testv.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x3741)
    #12 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #13 0x56431183fe20 in _Z5coro2v.actor(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x1e20)
    #14 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #15 0x564311841741 in _Z4testv.actor(test()::_Z4testv.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x3741)
    #16 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #17 0x56431183fe20 in _Z5coro2v.actor(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x1e20)
    #18 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #19 0x564311841741 in _Z4testv.actor(test()::_Z4testv.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x3741)
    #20 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #21 0x56431183fe20 in _Z5coro2v.actor(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x1e20)
    #22 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #23 0x564311841741 in _Z4testv.actor(test()::_Z4testv.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x3741)
    #24 0x564311840f15 in _Z5coro1v.actor(coro1()::_Z5coro1v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x2f15)
    #25 0x56431183fe20 in _Z5coro2v.actor(coro2()::_Z5coro2v.frame*) (/home/leonard/Desktop/hiwi/async_io_uring/stack_overflow/a.out+0x1e20)
```

Interestingly, if I compile with `clang++-12 main.cc type.cc -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fsanitize=address` the program does not trigger a stack-overflow and exits without any errors. Furthermore, if I omit `-fsanitize=address`, then I get a segmentation fault when using `-O3` and no error at all when using `-O0`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when playing around with coroutines. I am not 100% certain of the reason why
the stack builds up but this is what I think might happen.

First of all, I don't think symmetric transfer is a given, it depends on compiler optimization and in some cases it might be difficult for the compiler to make this tail-call transformation. One of the reason could be because of the non-trivial destructor that lays in another compilation unit for Type (this is just a guess).

Reading the blog post you mentioned, it says: "The bool-returning version, however, can have a slight win in terms of optimisability in some cases compared to the symmetric-transfer form.", so it might be because compiler support is not fully mature yet (?) and it might be a good alternative to try the bool-returning form instead.

I would love to have a good answer on this problem as well, just trying to give my opinion based on my current finding at the moment, so please don't take this answer as absolute truth.

---

**Edit:**

Here is a workaround that prevents the stack-overflow. It uses the `bool`-returning version of the `await_suspend()` function. Unfortunately, the workaround introduces other problems. For example, the `Task` type is not thread-safe anymore. For further information look at the section "The Coroutines TS solution" of the blog post [C++ Coroutines: Understanding Symmetric Transfer](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2020/05/11/understanding_symmetric_transfer).

```
// in main.cc
struct PromiseBase {
// ...
  struct final_awaitable {
  // ...
    template <typename PROMISE>
    void await_suspend(coro::coroutine_handle<PROMISE> coro) noexcept {
      if (coro.promise().m_continuation &&
          std::exchange(coro.promise().ready, true)) {
        // coro did not complete synchronously, therefore we need to resume
        // the continuation
        coro.promise().m_continuation.resume();
      }
    }
  // ...
  };

  bool ready{false};
// ...
};
```

```
// in main.cc
struct awaitable {
// ...
    // The bool returning version of await_suspend resumes awaitingCoroutine
    // without consuming any additional stack-space if the value false is
    // returned. Otherwise, it returns control to the caller/resumer of
    // awaitingCoroutine.
    bool await_suspend(coro::coroutine_handle<> awaitingCoroutine) noexcept {
      m_coroutine.promise().set_continuation(awaitingCoroutine);
      m_coroutine.resume();
      // resume awaitingCoroutine if m_coroutine completed synchronously
      return !std::exchange(m_coroutine.promise().ready, true);
    }
// ...
};
```

Comment: The blog post states that _"the compiler guarantees that this will always be a tail-call, regardless of whether optimisations are enabled or not"_. Therefore, I also believe that the compiler support is just not fully mature yet.

I tried your suggestion of using the `bool` returning version and this actually prevents the stack-overflow. I will edit your answer to include the necessary modifications to my code.